# how to set contentDescription for MenuItem for below API 26 in android?

Tags: android

I have a menuItem for book mark feature in a toolbar. I assign title and contentDescription for that menuItem on top_app_bar.xml by default and programmatically depending on their state either clicked or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    ...
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_bookmark_layout"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content_unbookmarked_layout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_bookmark_border_24"
        android:title="@string/content_unbookmarked_layout"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    ...

</menu>
```

top_app_bar.xml

```
    binding.tbWebview.setOnMenuItemClickListener { menuItem ->
        when (menuItem.itemId) {
        ...
            R.id.action_bookmark_layout -> {
                val isBookmarkCheckedPreviously = binding.tbWebview.menu.findItem(R.id.action_bookmark_layout).isChecked
                binding.tbWebview.menu.findItem(R.id.action_bookmark_layout).isChecked = !isBookmarkCheckedPreviously

                val isBookmarkCheckedNow = !isBookmarkCheckedPreviously
                if (isBookmarkCheckedNow) {
                    binding.tbWebview.menu.findItem(R.id.action_bookmark_layout).icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_bookmark_filled_24)
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        binding.tbWebview.menu.findItem(R.id.action_bookmark_layout).contentDescription = getString(R.string.content_bookmarked_layout)
                    }
                    binding.tbWebview.menu.findItem(R.id.action_bookmark_layout).title = getString(R.string.content_bookmarked_layout)
                } else {
                    binding.tbWebview.menu.findItem(R.id.action_bookmark_layout).icon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_bookmark_border_24)
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        binding.tbWebview.menu.findItem(R.id.action_bookmark_layout).contentDescription = getString(R.string.content_unbookmarked_layout)
                    }
                    binding.tbWebview.menu.findItem(R.id.action_bookmark_layout).title = getString(R.string.content_unbookmarked_layout)
                }

                true
            }
            else -> false
        }
    }
```

WebViewActivity.kt

I took the lint suggestion with if statement for API 26 or up since it seems it's introduced in API 26 in [MenuItem](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)). However, I would like to set the contentDescription for below API 26 as well since contentDescription has set to `@string/content_unbookmarked_layout` by default in xml file. How can I achieve that?